# .* expression in mysql not working

Tags: python, mysql, regex

I am trying to write a SQL query in a pyhton script to automate gathering a collection of information based on hosts in my environment every 15 days. To do this, I need to use regex because there are a lot of name variations I am working with, so using LIKE is not an option, otherwise I would have about 80 likes.

One of the issues I am running into is, some of the names have the identifier in the middle. Normally, hosts are named something like Desktop-Acc-1515 or something like that. But networking devices (designed before I started working here) are named like this "set151-router-b1-5b42". Thats a rough idea of how it is.

Normally, I would use a regex of something like `.*-router-.*` which works in a normal environment, but MySQL does not seem to like that as it returns 0 results with -router- in it.

So how can I perform a MySQL regex query to look for "anything" on both sides of -router-

Here is a redacted version of what I am doing sort of.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT Count(distinct table1.HostName)
FROM vulnerability
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.Id = table2.Id
LEFT JOIN table3  on table1.Id = table3.Id
LEFT JOIN table4  on table1.Id = table4.Id
LEFT JOIN table5  on table1.Id = table5.Id
LEFT JOIN table6  on table1.Id = table6.Id
WHERE table1.UpdateDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY) 
AND table2.InstallDate > (NOW() - INTERVAL 20 DAY) 
AND table1.Hostname REGEXP
"Desktop-(Oregon|Idaho|Wyoming)|WorkStation-(Oregon|Idaho|Wyoming)|(.*-router-.*)"
```

Update/Edit

Oddly enough, if I do a regex of JUST `(.*-router-.*)` it works, but adding it to the rest of my regex, it doesn't return any results, not sure why?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Updated. I had to redact a lot of information from it, and made the sample regex much smaller.

Comment: Is the `*` in the regex a literal? If so, it is also a metacharacter that needs to be escaped `\*` to be a literal. Otherwise, it is a quantifier. But quantifiers can't quantify other metacharacters. So, as is, it will throw.. because the `(` is also a metacharacter.

Comment: I am a fairly big regex novice... so I am not sure. All I know is I use .* because it basically says anything is ok.

Comment: It might be worth posting a couple of sample text lines that regex intends to match. Being a novice and posting an ambiguous regex, is like 2 equations and 3 unknowns.

Comment: Posting fyi: If you replace the regex with something now valid, you should redact `" Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp 0.090 sec"`

Comment: Added a sample of what I am trying to match. 
`set151-router-b1-5b42`

So I want to match anything that has `-router-` in it because router is the only part that is static.

Comment: `JUST (.*-router-.*) it works, but adding it to the rest` - Your regex is basically three alternatives. `this|that|other`. If you use just `other` and it matches, it will still match `other` in the alternative form. That's just the way regexes work ..

Comment: Why all the _States_ in the regex, what part do they play?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're looking for something like this `(?:.*?(?:Desktop-(Oregon|Idaho|Wyoming)|WorkStation-(Oregon|Idaho|Wyoming)))?(.*-router-.*)` where the states are optional.

Comment: regular expressions in mysql are not rooted anyway, so `.*-router-.*` has the same effect as `-router-`, if you want to match against the whole pattern you need to use `^(...)$`.

Comment: I hope those tables do not have the same `id`!  Please do not obfuscate to the point of incorrectness.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that it WAS working, the problem is that the -routers- don't match the other things such as updatedate and installdate. So the regex works fine with `.*-router-.*`

Comment: Please delete the question, since it provides nothing but embarrassment.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid regex anywhere - seems like you are getting mixed up with shell wildcards, which aren't the same.

You need something for the * to repeat - for example `(.*-router-.*)`.

Comment: I tried that. I did (.*-router-.*) but I get 0 results with router in the name, even though if I pull up the table I can see at least 50 devices with that naming convention.